# Error piping/redirecting from a file or command in windows

Tags: c, redirect, piping

I made a program that I then used to create a file from its output, now I want to make one of several programs to run redirecting that file (or piping the output of the other programs to it).
I used the following code as a test for the first program

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    long long int n = 0;
    char str[100];

    while (str != NULL)
    {
        fscanf(stdin,"%s\0", str);
        printf("%lld\t%s\n", n, str);

        n++;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The program executes correctly until the last line of the redirected file or piped output, which then keeps repearing infinitely until I stop the execution with ctrl-c (Windows).
I don't know why this happens, I tried flushing stdin, stdout and everything that I had think of and no luck.

What I am doing wrong or missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `str != NULL` can never be false. Look at the scanf docs to see what it does in case of errors/end-of-stream conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (str != NULL)
{
    fscanf(stdin,"%s\0", str);
    printf("%lld\t%s\n", n, str);

    n++;
}
```

replaced by

```
while (scanf("%s", str) != EOF)
{
    printf("%lld\t%s\n", n, str);
    n++;
}
```

Solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[100];
while (str != NULL)
```

`str` is treated as a pointer to the first character in the array, so its value never changes, which means the loop will never terminate.

Comment: changing the condition to check the return value of scanf yeilds the same result too.